# Not able to use JSON Macro Inception to convert nested JSON structure to Scala case class object

Tags: json, scala, macros, playframework-2.0

I have a requirement where the incoming JSON object is complex and mostly nested
ex:

```
"users": {
  "utype": "PERSON",
  "language":"en_FR",
  "credentials": [
    {          
      "handle": "xyz@abc.com",
      "password": "123456",
      "handle_type": "EMAIL"
    }
  ],
  "person_details": {
    "primary": "true",
    "names": [
      {
      "name_type": "OFFICIAL",
      "title": "MR",
      "given": "abc",
      "family": "zat",
      "middle": "pqs",
      "suffix":"anathan"
     }
    ],
    "addresses": [
      {
        "ad_type": "HOME",
        "line1": "Residential 2211 North 1st Street",
        "line2": "Bldg 17",
        "city": "test",
        "county": "Shefield",
        "state" : "NY",
        "country_code": "xx",
        "postal_code": "95131"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For parsing this structure I use the below Case Classes

```
case class PersonUser (
    user_type:String,
    language_code:String,
    credentials:List[Credential],
    person_details:PersonDetails
)

case class Credential(handle:String, password:String,handle_type:String)

case class PersonDetails(
    primary_user:Boolean,
    names: List[Name],
    addresses:List[Address]
)

case class Name(
    name_type: String,
    title: String,
    given: String,
    family: String,
    middle: String,
    suffix:String
)

case class Address(
    address_type: String,
    line1: String,
    line2: String,
    city: String,
    county: String,
    state : String,
    country_code: String,
    postal_code: String
)
```

The statement to convert the json to scala case class object is failing:

```
implicit val testReads = Json.reads[PersonUser]
```

The errors says:

```
[scala-play-rest-example] $ compile
[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources to C:\Personal\Scala\scala-play-rest-example-master\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[error] C:\Personal\Scala\scala-play-rest-example-master\app\controllers\user\UserController.scala:16: **No implicit Reads for List[controllers.user.Credential], controllers.user.PersonDetails available.**
[error]     implicit val testReads = Json.reads[PersonUser]
```

Can someone please help me out to find out a way to represent complex json structure in Scala and convert it using Macro Inception or some other ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create `Reads` for all of your case classes, not just the top-level.  For instance:

```
case class Credential(handle:String, password:String,handle_type:String)

object Credential {

  implicit val reads = Json.reads[Credential]

}
```

Once you have those, `Json.reads[PersonUser]` will be able to work.

Comment: Did you create `Reads` for *all* of the component types of `PersonUser`?

Comment: Hello Ryan I take that back, it is working. Actually I kept all the case classes in one file and the PersonUser was the first case class defined and all the sub classes below. Because of which the compiler was not able to detect them properly. When I inverted the definition order, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I have couple of questions further:
1. If we have to define implicit reads by defining Companion object for each case class (which has companion already as it is case class), it is going to be cumbersome. Suppose I have 4 other sub jsons inside my PersonUser, I will have to totally wrie 4 + 1 Case classes and as many Objects also. Is there any way to  tell reads and writes to be auto added?

Comment: 2nd question: Regarding the earlier issue I faced due to Class definition order. Is there any suggestion about this issue? Should we separately put these classes in individual files so that this problem never happens? If that is the case, like Java, its restricting us. Any ideas/suggestion?

Comment: Yes, you need to put the `Reads` in companion objects.  I don't remember the details on code order though.

Answer (score 1):

One other approach regarding the implicit reads/writes/format can be to define them in a separate helper object. Implicit in the object must be defined in a specific order like in your case the order of the implicit must be :-

```
object JsonHelper {
  implicit val nameReads = Json.reads[Name]
  implicit val addressReads = Json.reads[Address]  //position of 'nameReads' and 'addressReads' is interchangable
  implicit val credentialReads = Json.reads[Credential]
  implicit val personReads = Json.reads[PersonDetails]  // similarly position of 'credentialReads' and 'personReads' is interchangable
  implicit val personUserReads = Json.reads[PersonUser]  //'personUserReads' will always be the last
}
```

From the above code it can be learnt that the reads of case classe at the bottom of nesting hierarchy must be defined first, followed by the top case classes.

Now you just need to 'import JsonHelper._' in your service or wherever you are converting your JsValue to scala case class. :)